# Linq: Non-static-methods-requires-a-target with select new {model}

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, c#-4.0

I have this LINQ query that returns a Non-static-method exception, because the left join sometimes returns a null value for context.Betas.

```
return (from t in context.Alphas
                join b in context.Betas on new { Id = t.Id } equals new { Id = b.AlphaId } into b_leftjoin
                from b in b_leftjoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where
                  t.UserProfileId == userProfileId
                  && t.IsClosed == false
                  && t.IsCancel == false
                  && t.EndDate <= DateTime.Now
                orderby
                  t.Title
                select new AlphaSelection()
                {
                    Title = t.Title,
                    CurrentUser = b.UserProfile == null ? null : b.UserProfile,
                    BetaId = b.Id == null ? 0 : b.Id,
                    ProjectNumber = t.ProjectNumber,
                    AlphaId = t.Id
                }).ToList();
```

If I remove the CurrentUser and BetaId the query works, but I need to keep all information together. Could you help me please to solve that problem?

Thanks!!

---

Edit (answering to comments):

The actual exception is this one:

Non-static method requires a target.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.Reflection.TargetException: Non-static method requires a target.

Source Error:


Line 39:             else
Line 40:             {
Line 41:                 return query.ToList();
Line 42:             }
Line 43:         }
```

Comment: What is the **actual** exception?

Comment: Could you give the *exact* details of the exception? It's unclear at the moment.

Comment: What is the type of `Id`? And why are you using `new {}` to do your join?

Comment: The the of Id is a integer and I use new to do my join because I use Sql to linq tool to format it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting a null reference exception. It is called a non-static target exception since LINQ uses reflection in the backend to do its thing.

```
CurrentUser = b.UserProfile == null ? null : b.UserProfile,
BetaId = b.Id == null ? 0 : b.Id,
```

Is causing it, you need to do

```
CurrentUser = b == null ? null : b.UserProfile,
BetaId = b == null ? 0 : b.Id,
```

Since the default value of a reference type is null.

Comment: Or you could use `??` instead of `whatever == null ? defaultval : whatever`

Comment: Really nice!! Thank you very much!! =D

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance: Not in this case, his original was in that form, but the correct version is not, the condition checks `b` while the final result uses a part of `b`.