# Non-static method requires a target. cant find an answer that seems to work

Tags: c#, linq

Every post I have found suggests that this happens when there is a `null` value. I have tried examples such as one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944034/linq-non-static-methods-requires-a-target-with-select-new-model) but no matter what I seem to try I still end up with the same error message.

Does anyone have any idea of what the case could be?

```
var aaresults1 = (from a in db.AAs
                  where a.AAID == aaid.AAID & a != null
                  select a);
```

Comment: You're using a bitwise `&` operator, not the logical `&&` operator. Is this intended?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - no, here the `&` is the full-eval _boolean_ operator.

Comment: scripter: post a _full_ compiling example. And the exact error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading through other StackOverflow posts about this error, it appears to happen when a `where` clause refers to a value that is null. Based on that, I'm guessing that your `aaid` object is null when you run this.

```
var aaresults1 = db.AAs.AsQueryable();
if(aaid != null)
{
    aaresults1 = aaresults1.Where(a => a.AAID == aaid.AAID);
}
```

Comment: I wish I would have seen a post previously that said specifically that it was in the where clause. I didn't even look at that because I thought I actually had another statement above this one Further up the code that used the same info and it worked. my fault I placed it too far up, anyhow thank you this fixed this problem now I can go beack to my original issues